# React not loading images, wrong url when being served by nginx server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack

after building with webpack one example of an image is pointing to this url

https://example.com/dist/js1f202d86a9aaef300a59a33d5eb48e55.gif

After some trying and error I found that the correct path is this

https://example.com/js/1f202d86a9aaef300a59a33d5eb48e55.gif

what should I do. If more info is need please ask me.

Comment: Hi Diego you question lacking details. Where did you deploy your frontend code? Or is running locally? Anyway, it looks like you need to point nginx's www root to the `dist` directory l, since there webpack placed the built version of your frontend